# How to deploy a Google Apps Script web app with clasp?

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I am using [clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp#deploy) to manage a Google Sheets Script (web app)

I tried to make a new deploy according to the [instructions](https://github.com/google/clasp#deploy) using: `clasp deploy --deploymentId abcd1234`

The command went through without errors. I can see a new version of the script created but the deployment is not updated: no deployment is made.

Answer (score 4):

I found this [conversation](https://github.com/google/clasp/issues/63) when digging deeper.

Summary: You need to add some code to your manifest file appscript.json:

```
  "webapp": {
    "access": "MYSELF",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
```

The whole appscript.json file should look like this (so you can see where to place the code:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "MYSELF",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

Furthermore here is an overview of the different options available:

```
"webapp": {
    "access": "MYSELF",
    "access": "ANYONE",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING"
    "executeAs": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS"
  },
```

After updating the manifest file push the changes using `clasp push`. Then deploy with the commands in the instructions: `clasp deploy --deploymentId abcd1234`

Additional note to anyone new to clasp: there is a difference between version and deployment. A version is similar to a git tag (a way of keeping track of code), while a deployment is actual code that is being used for execution.